# Customising Corner Radius of a Frame in Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Why do we need to retrieve the background of our native Control and casts it to GradientDrawable while customizing the CornerRadius property of a Frame using a CustomRenderer?I've added the code for my customrender below.

```
private void UpdateCornerRadius()
    {
        if (Control.Background is GradientDrawable _gradientbackground)
        {
            var cornerRadius = (Element as CustomFrame)?.CornerRadius;
            if (!cornerRadius.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }

            var topLeftCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.TopLeft);
            var topRightCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.TopRight);
            var bottomLeftCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.BottomLeft);
            var bottomRightCorner = Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius.Value.BottomRight);

            var cornerRadii = new[]
            {
                topLeftCorner,
                topLeftCorner,

                topRightCorner,
                topRightCorner,

                bottomRightCorner,
                bottomRightCorner,

                bottomLeftCorner,
                bottomLeftCorner,
            };

            _gradientbackground.SetCornerRadii(cornerRadii);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms Frame control has a CornerRadius  property so you don't need to a Custom Renderer. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mouse On Mars mentioned in his comment, you don't need to do it in a custom renderer. The [Frame control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame#round-elements) has the ability to round corners. Unfortunately it lacks the ability to round specific corners (e.g. rounding only top corners) or apply different rounding radius to different corners. Not to worry though, there's an excellent nuget package called [PancakeView](https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView) by an Microsoft MVP [Steven Thewissen](https://twitter.com/devnl), that will help you with just that.Read through the Github documentation, it's really easy to start with.